# .htaccess redirect except certain directories or files?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have a Wordpress site and WP supplies a .htaccess which includes the following:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

That redirects all requests to http://*mydomain.com*/index.php.

How do I prevent redirects for, e.g., http://*mydomain.com*/tools or http://*mydomain.com*/tools/stats.php?

Comment: I am still seeing the redirects. :( and will investigate further.

Comment: Important note: this question is really about REWRITE not REDIRECT but the answers apply to both. REWRITE performs internal redirection. The Redirect directive maps an old URL into a new one by asking the client to refetch the resource at the new location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If tools is a directory, and tools/stats.php is a file, they are already excluded by the two `RewriteCond` lines.

Answer (score 0):

The [L] is the "last rule" which is similar to "break" in code, see the [docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule). So add more "last"-line-patterns right after the first index.php line.

(And while I write this: Dan makes a good point that already existing dirs or files are ignored already)

Comment: The block is automagically added to the .htaccess file by Wordpress I never knew it did this but it makes sense. - Anyhoo - I would have to include my own similar block with rewrites ABOVE the Wordpress generated block but your point is very helpful.

e.g.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteRule ^tools/ - [L]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress